# jq extracting the object key based on value of nested property

Tags: arrays, jq

Given this JSON:

```
{
    "{c156e78e-a4ac-422b-bf86-afe12f548dfb}": {
        "name": "after-gluster3.8",
        "date": "2017-04-16 14:31:20",
        "state": "poweron",
        "current": false,
        "parent": ""
    }
    ,
    "{d773d5b7-94d4-4f78-a943-f50e4eb68fe0}": {
        "name": "after-sshd-fixes",
        "date": "2017-04-16 16:58:32",
        "state": "poweroff",
        "current": true,
        "parent": "{c156e78e-a4ac-422b-bf86-afe12f548dfb}"
    }
}
```

I'm in need to extract the key, based on the value of name, ie. I'm searching for `"after-sshd-fixes"` and then want `"{d773d5b7-94d4-4f78-a943-f50e4eb68fe0}"` as output.

using `.[]` throws away the key of the array, and I'm a bit overwhelmed with the rest of the jq manual to figure out how to put the key of the array into a temporary value, do the test, and then to output the specific array key:value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***jq*** approach:

```
jq 'to_entries[] | select(.value.name == "after-sshd-fixes").key' jsonfile
```

The output:

```
"{d773d5b7-94d4-4f78-a943-f50e4eb68fe0}"
```

Comment: got myself to the below , and as I wanted to answer myself, see yours:
```cat file.json | jq 'with_entries(.value.test += .key)|.[] |select(.name == "after-sshd-fixes")' | jq -r ' .test'```