# JQ get key based on variable value

Tags: bash, sh, jq, oh-my-zsh

I'm trying to create a ohmyzsh function for Salesforce's DX CLI based on Wade Wegner's guide [here](http://www.wadewegner.com/2017/04/show-the-salesforce-dx-org-config-in-your-bash-profile/#comment-3671894553). In order to get the value I want I need to expand how he is using [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) which I've never heard of before. I get the premise for this use case but I'm struggling with one abstraction point (within the `aliasConfig` json). Here's my script so far

```
get_sfdx_defaultusername() {
    config="$(cat .sfdx/sfdx-config.json 2> /dev/null)";
    globalConfig="$(cat ~/.sfdx/sfdx-config.json)";
    aliasConfig="$(cat ~/.sfdx/alias.json)";

    defaultusername="$(echo ${config} | jq -r .defaultusername)"
    defaultusernamealias="NEED HELP HERE"
    globaldefaultusername="$(echo ${globalConfig} | jq -r .defaultusername)"

    if [ ! $defaultusernamealias = "null" ]
    then
      echoString=$echoString$defaultusernamealias"$txtylw (alias)"
    elif [ ! $defaultusername = "null" ]
    then
      echoString=$echoString$defaultusername"$txtylw (local)"
    else
      echoString=$echoString$globaldefaultusername"$txtylw (global)"
    fi
    echo $echoString"\n"
}
```

The **alias.json** looks like this:

```
{
    "orgs": {
        "HubOrg": "myemail@domain.com",        
        "my-scrath-org": "test-jdj1iflkor4k@mydomain.net"
    }
}
```

Using the `${defaultusername}` I know the value in this case to be "test-jdj1iflkor4k@mydomain.net", therefore I need it to set the value of `defaultusernamealias` to "my-scrath-org"

NOTE: The closest answer I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678724/jq-extracting-the-array-key-based-on-value), but unfortunately I still couldn't get what I needed with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations on figuring out how to use `to_entries`.

One small suggestion is to avoid using shell interpolation to "construct" the jq program.  A much better way to achieve the desired goal is to pass in the relevant values on the command-line. In your case, the following would be appropriate:

```
$ jq --arg username "$defaultusername" '
  .orgs | to_entries[] | select(.value == $username ).key'
```

Another small point is to avoid using `echo` to send JSON to STDIN. There are several possibilities, including these patterns:

- if you are using bash: `jq .... <<< "$JSON"`
- use `printf "%s" "$JSON" | jq ...`
- `jq -n --argjson JSON "$JSON" '$JSON | ...'`

In your case, the last of these alternatives would look like this:

```
$ jq --arg username "$defaultusername" --argjson JSON "$aliasConfig" '
    $JSON
    | .orgs | to_entries[] | select(.value == $username ).key'
```

Comment: Appreciate that. I was able to implement your first suggestion without an issue. Can you show me how you would rewrite your second? I'm currently using `sh` but I suppose someone on Windows attempting this may need a `.bash` version as well.

Comment: Fixed a typo and elaborated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it figured out here:

```
get_sfdx_defaultusername() {
    config="$(cat .sfdx/sfdx-config.json 2> /dev/null)";
    globalConfig="$(cat ~/.sfdx/sfdx-config.json)";
    aliasConfig="$(cat ~/.sfdx/alias.json)";

    defaultusername="$(echo ${config} | jq -r .defaultusername)"
    defaultusernamealias="$(echo ${aliasConfig} | jq -r '.orgs | to_entries[] | select(.value =="'$defaultusername'").key' )"
    globaldefaultusername="$(echo ${globalConfig} | jq -r .defaultusername)"

    if [ ! $defaultusernamealias = "null" ]
    then
        echoString=$echoString$defaultusernamealias"$txtylw (alias)"
    elif [ ! $defaultusername = "null" ]
    then
        echoString=$echoString$defaultusername"$txtylw (local)"
    else
        echoString=$echoString$globaldefaultusername"$txtylw (global)"
    fi
    echo $echoString"\n"
}
```

This allows me to show my current defaultusername org like so:
[image]

In case anyone is interested in using this or contributing to it, I published a [github repo here](https://github.com/Xtremefaith/sfdx-ohmyzsh)